# Display file path of documents in Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that lists invoices and I would like to be able to show the file path of the invoices in another column of the report.  The following query allows me to search for the documents based on their unique ID number.  It then displays the file location of the one document I search for, however I would like to have this apply to all of the documents listed in the report.  Can someone please help me out with this?

```
    `DECLARE @entryID INT = 35793

SELECT dbo.toc.name AS DocumentName, dbo.doc.pagenum + 1 AS PageNum, dbo.vol.fixpath + '\' + 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), dbo.doc.storeid),2),1,2) + '\' + 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), dbo.doc.storeid),2),3,2) + '\' +
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), dbo.doc.storeid),2),5,2) + '\' +
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), dbo.doc.storeid),2) + '.TIF' AS FullPathAndFilename
FROM dbo.doc  
LEFT JOIN dbo.toc ON dbo.doc.tocid = dbo.toc.tocid
LEFT JOIN dbo.vol ON dbo.toc.vol_id = dbo.vol.vol_id
WHERE dbo.doc.tocid = @entryID
ORDER BY dbo.doc.pagenum`
```

Comment: couldn't able to understand your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on how you currently retrieve data in the existing Crystal Report.

**Option A:** If your report data source is a "Command" (in other words you have written a SQL statement in the crystal report that retrieves the data you need), then you will want to modify that command to pull in this new information via a subquery. So for example if your current report SQL is something like "select x.* from foo as x", you would want it to be something like:

```
select x.*, 
    (SELECT dbo.vol.fixpath + '\' 
     + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), dbo.doc.storeid),2),1,2) + '\' 
     + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), dbo.doc.storeid),2),3,2) + '\' 
     + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), dbo.doc.storeid),2),5,2) + '\' 
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), dbo.doc.storeid),2) 
     + '.TIF' AS FullPathAndFilename
     FROM dbo.doc  
     LEFT JOIN dbo.toc ON dbo.doc.tocid = dbo.toc.tocid
     LEFT JOIN dbo.vol ON dbo.toc.vol_id = dbo.vol.vol_id
     WHERE dbo.doc.tocid = x.tocid   //this line joining the new SQL to all report rows
    )
from foo as x;
```

**Option B:** If instead you pull your data from Crystal using the join wizard, then it would probably be best to create a new view in your database that matches the SQL you provided (minus the last 2 lines), and then join your existing main report tables to this view in the Crystal join wizard.